# Unit testing in ASP.NET/C# using monodevelop and NUnit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nunit, monodevelop

I'm developing a webapp using ASP.NET MVC and C# using Monodevelop IDE and unit testing using NUnit plugin for monodevelop in ubuntu OS. How do I implement the unit testing for my setup?

Please advise.

Many thanks.

Comment: I think you need to be much more specific with your question. What is it that's not working?

Comment: Are you asking how do I run unit tests in monodevelop?